# Getting the five sequential combinations of the words

Tags: java

So I am trying to get the five sequential of the words. I have this input:

> Pacific Ocean is the largest of the Earth's oceanic divisions

Output should be like:

```
 Pacific
 Pacific Ocean
 Pacific Ocean is
 Pacific Ocean is the
 Pacific Ocean is the largest
 Ocean
 Ocean is
 Ocean is the
 Ocean is the largest
 Ocean is the largest of
 is
 is the
 is the largest
 is the largest of
 is the largest of the
 the
 the largest
 the largest of
 the largest of the
 the largest of the Earth's
 largest
 largest of
 largest of the
 largest of the Earth's
 largest of the Earth's oceanic
 of
 of the
 of the Earth's
 of the Earth's oceanic
 of the Earth's oceanic divisions
 the
 the Earth's
 the Earth's oceanic
 the Earth's oceanic divisions
 Earth's
 Earth's oceanic
 Earth's oceanic divisions
 oceanic
 oceanic divisions
 divisions
```

**My attempt:**

```
public void getComb(String line) {
    String words[] = line.split(" ");
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = "";
        int m = i;
        while (count < 5) {
            count++;
            word += " " + words[m];
            System.out.println(word);
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is wrong! Output:

```
 Pacific
 Pacific Ocean
 Pacific Ocean is
 Pacific Ocean is the
 Pacific Ocean is the largest
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the position of the snippet `count = 0`:

```
public void getComb(String line) {
    String words[] = line.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;   // RESET COUNT
        String word = "";
        int m = i;
        while (count < 5 && m < words.length) { // NO EXCEPTION with 'm' limit
            count++;
            word += " " + words[m];
            System.out.println(word);
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when you reach the last four words...

Comment: yeah. I am getting out of bounds index 10

Answer (score 4):

Use a nested for-loop instead of the while loop and advance the start word in the outer loop:

```
public static void getComb(String line) {
    String words[] = line.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = "";

        for (int w = i; w < ((i + 5 < words.length) ? (i + 5) : words.length); w++) {
            word += " " + words[w];
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `((i + 5 < words.length) ? (i + 5) : words.length)`in the condition in the inner for-loop; it's needed so that you don't access elements beyond the array when there's less than five words left - without it you would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

Formally, you want to find [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) of sizes 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 from your string. The [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) class in the Apache Lucene library can be used for this. From the JavaDoc:

> A ShingleFilter constructs shingles (token n-grams) from a token stream. In other words, it creates combinations of tokens as a single token.
>   For example, the sentence "please divide this sentence into shingles" might be tokenized into shingles "please divide", "divide this", "this sentence", "sentence into", and "into shingles".

Answer (score 1):

Try the below approach..modified version of Andynedine

```
public void getComb(String line)
{
    String words[] = line.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        int count=0;   //******* RESET CONT *****//
        String word = "";
        int m=i;
        while(count<5 && m < 10)
        {
            count++;
            word += " "+words[m];
            System.out.println(word);
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```